# What is the jQuery equivalent of "return" in Ruby?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, return

I'm referring to the `return` that quits running the function.

Comment: Please note that when you're writing jQuery code, the language you're using is Javascript. jQuery is a (very extensive) library for Javascript.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Yeah I know, I just never formally learned javascript, so I'm learning jQuery before it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the same `return x;` and it will return the value.

```
function(x,y){    
   return x+y;
}
```

Comment: can I just do `return` if I don't want to return anything and I just want the function to stop running?

Comment: yea, just a simple return; will do.

Answer (score 2):

`return` will do just that, although because ruby methods will always return the value produced by the last expression, most developers don't use it explicitly.